# Find the distance between an ancestor element and a child element

Tags: jquery

I have both jQuery objects to the ancestor parent and the child element.

```
$ancestor = ...;
$child = ...;
```

How do I get the distance between the two? I.e. how many elements are in this ancestry chain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the elements between two other elements including those elements:

```
var $els = $child.parentsUntil($ancestor).andSelf()
```

Or to just get a number of how many elements are there in between:

```
var elsInBetween = $child.parentsUntil($ancestor).length - 1
```

Comment: Well... you learn something new every day! Big ol' +1 from me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be of assistance -

```
var counter = 0;
var target = '';
while($child.parent().length){
  target = $child.parent();
  counter++;
}
console.log(target);
```

I am simply iterating over the `parent()` object each time round replacing each time with its parent.  You'll get ALL the ancestors here... And I mean **all** of them.

Comment: `.parent()` will never return `null`

Comment: @esa - thanks for that insight.  You are indeed correct.  I've fixed the post.